# Show a set in a metric space is dense, if and only if, the metric space is the union of open balls.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that if $(X, d)$ is a metric space, $S \subseteq X$ is dense *if and only if*, $\space \forall r > 0$, $X = \bigcup_{x\in S}B(x; r)$.

This problem has been confusing me, as I've tried to justify that, starting from the left, since
$\bar S  = X$ I could show $\bar S = \bigcup_{x\in S}B(x; r)$ and conclude that $X = \bigcup_{x\in S}B(x; r)$.

I don't know what to do since I'm mostly confused by how the closure of a set could be the union of all of the open balls in $X$, especially when the union of all of the open balls would be open.

I've included some definitions to show the framework I'm working in. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

**Definitions:**

Given a metric space $(X, d)$:

- A set $S \subseteq X$ is ***dense*** if $\bar S  = X$.
- Given a set $S \subseteq X$, the ***closure*** of $S$ is $\bar S  =  
     \{\space x\in X \space | \space \forall r>0, B(x;r)\cap S\neq   
     \emptyset \}$.
- The ***open ball*** is defined as $B(x;r)= \{a\in X \space | \space d(x,a)<r\}$.

---

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that fact directly comes from the definition of metric space topology on $X$.

Answer (score 4):

It suffices to show that show that $X\subset \bigcup_{s\in S}B(s; r)$ (the other inclusion is trivial).

Let $x\in X$ then, since $S$ is dense in $X$, i. e. $\bar S  = X$, it follows that for any
$r>0$, $B(x;r)\cap S\neq   
   \emptyset$. Let $y$ be an element of the non-empty set $B(x;r)\cap S$ then $d(y,x)<r$ AND $y\in S$, which means that $$x\in B(y;r)\subset \bigcup_{s\in S}B(s; r).$$

Comment: I understand this completely; I didn't about using an element in B(x;r)∩S for this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DallasW. You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Clearly, $$\bigcup B(r, x) \subset X.$$ We have to prove now that $$X\subset \bigcup B(r, x).$$ Suppose $x\in X$. In order to prove that x lies in the union, we have to prove that there exists $B(r, y)$ such that $x \in B(r, y)$.